# getJSON function is not executing

Tags: c#, javascript, json, highcharts

I am trying to call a simple data.json file, code is given below,

```
alert("outside");
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("inside");
        $("#myButton").click(function () {

            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'spline'
                },
                series: [{}]
            };
        });


        $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
            alert("read");
            options.series[0].data = data;
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });

    });
```

and below is my data.json content

```
[{"series_name":"Actual","period_name":"Q1 / 2013","period_final_value":"17"},
{"series_name":"Actual","period_name":"Q2 / 2013","period_final_value":"15"}]
```

I tried by inserting alerts as well, it seems getJSON doesn't read my json file. Since I am new to JSON, I might be wrong in calling function,any help will be greatly appreciated.I have also referred highcharts, my main aim is to plot the graph on highcharts by reading the value from json file.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: no error..simple function is not called,I got to know since alert inside the function getJSON doesn't appear.

Comment: Try changing the file extension to js.

Comment: That function only runs on success. Run this with Fiddle2 and check the server response code.

Comment: @RobinL "second success" is very amusing to me for some reason

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to run in fiddle since I don't know how to read the file that is data.json externally.can you please guide me on the same

Comment: I advice you to check how series obejct should look like, becase this form is not correct. You can prepare json, durign preprocessing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first step, try this code to find out what the error is.

Also look in the networking tab of Chrome dev tools to find out what network activity is taking place.

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function() {

     alert("success");

})
.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

Comment: .success(function() { alert("second success"); })...this line doesnot execute, rest all alerts are shown

Comment: So you need to initialize chart in first funciton body, but with $.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {}); constirucin, then in data you will have your json.